# How to express $a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$ with $a_1=1$ and $a_2=1$, i.e., it is  $\{1,1,2,3,5,8,13, \dots\}$. I don't know what is $a_n$, i.e., how to express $a_n$?

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Isn't it the Fibonacci's?

Comment: Are you back to asking questions just for the sake of earning some meaningless points? It is quite peculiar that somebody knows about ccc and whatever exotic things in point-set topology but pretends that he cannot answer high-school level questions.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for your comments. One thing that I must explain that I don't intend to earn something. Recently, I am reviewing something about mathematical analysis and doing some exercise to prepare to be a good teacher by teaching students in college. There is something I am not sure. So I post it here to make more clearer for me. Sorry for the misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The charecteristic equation is
$$r^2=r+1$$
and it's roots are
$$r_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\quad r_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
hence
$$a_n=\alpha(r_1)^n+\beta(r_2)^n$$
We determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by $a_1$ and $a_2$

Comment: Which shows the Golden ratio.

Answer (score 3):

This sequence of numbers is known as the Fibonacci sequence. You can find more information [here (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and [here (OEIS)](http://oeis.org/A000045).